# Duplicate Local variable session (javax.jms.Session)

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, jms

I am trying to send some message into ActiveMQ in my jsp page. But I am getting the issue with Session (javax.jms.Session) variable declaration. If I declare the session variable locally I am getting the (`Duplicate local session variable session`) issue. If I declare my variables globally I am getting (`Type mismatch: cannot convert session to httpsession`) error. 
MY code,

```
<%@page import="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.Connection" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.Destination" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.JMSException" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.MessageProducer" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.Session" %>
<%@page import="javax.jms.TextMessage" %>


<%-- <%!
    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Destination destination = null;
    private MessageProducer producer = null;   

%> --%>


 <portlet:defineObjects />
 <theme:defineObjects />
 <%
     final ConnectionFactory factory = null;
     final Connection connection = null;
     final Session session = null;
     final Destination destination = null;
     final MessageProducer producer = null;  

         try {
                factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
                connection = factory.createConnection();
                connection.start();
                session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                destination = session.createQueue("SAMPLEQUEUE");
                producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText(formData);
                producer.send(message);
                System.out.println("Sent: " + message);

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
%>
```

But the same code is working fine in servlet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

because you defined the object `session` two times:

```
<%-- <%!
    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null; //<-- HERE
```

and here

```
<theme:defineObjects />
 <%
     final ConnectionFactory factory = null;
     final Connection connection = null;
     final Session session = null; // <-- HERE
```

remove at least one of them or rename one of the local variable's session.

I think in your servlet you have one member and one local variable which is absolutly valid.

Comment: I have commented the global variables. private Session session = null;  is in commented code.

Comment: that does not work when there is another jsp tag inside the comment.

Comment: I tried by removing the local variables.  I am getting (Type mismatch: cannot convert session to httpsession) error. If I use local varibles and deleting he global variables  I am getting the (Duplicate local session variable session) issue.